# How to Convert short unsigned to short signed in Android?

Tags: java, android

How to convert a short unsigned to short signed in android? Though char hold same of short unsigned but I don't want to cast every time with char.
Is there any best way for conversion ?

Comment: If the unsigned short values would fit in a short (< 0x8000) then keep it the values in a short. Otherwise keep the value in an int (and alway cast when storing in a short).

Comment: Thanks, but if I have a structure like unsigned short iAdd,  unsigned short iSub,  unsigned short iMul,  unsigned short iDiv,  unsigned short iRem..etc all the time i have to check and cast for short ..(coz i wanted to convert list of unsigned short to short which hold 2 bytes )

Answer (score 2):

Use an `int` and assign the value with a bitwise and.

```
int unsignedValue = shortValue & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: Whoa, you're a life-saver!!